# Android TabLayout not reloading fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-tabs, androiddesignsupport

I noticed the `TabLayout` only loads the `Fragments` it has to display once, so when I replace the `Fragment` containing the `TabLayout` and switch back to it, it does not recreate the `Fragments` it holds, and thus they are no longer displaying anything. Is this by design like that or am I doing something wrong? I am using the outer `Fragment` in a `NavigationDrawer`, and when the user switches to another `Fragment` and back, the tab `Fragments` are empty because they don't get recreated. I also noticed the Tabs act really strange after I switch back to the fragment containing them (they white line below jumps and you can hold it still between the two tabs without touching the screen)

The code I'm using:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    private static ViewPager viewPager;
    private static TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Utils.changeLanguage(getActivity());

        final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.LinesOverlay);

        LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);

        View view = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        LinesTabsAdapter adapter = new LinesTabsAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment2(), "Fragment 1");
        adapter.addFragment(new Fragment3(), "Fragment 2");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public static class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_lines_driving, container, false);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }

    public static class Fragment3 extends Fragment  {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_lines_all, container, false);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

LinesTabsAdapter:

```
public class LinesTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> fragmentTiles = new ArrayList<>();

    public LinesTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
        fragmentTiles.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTiles.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I noticed the TabLayout only loads the fragments" -- [`TabLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) has nothing to do with fragments. `ViewPager` has nothing to do with fragments. `LinesTabsAdapter` presumably is involved with fragments.

Comment: The code in setupViewPager should load the fragment, right?

Comment: I have no idea. AFAIK, you wrote `LinesTabsAdapter`, as there is no such class in the Android SDK. The only reason it appears to be involved with fragments is that your appear to be passing fragments into it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added the LinesTabAdapter in the question

Comment: You'll have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end of `addFragment(...)` and anytime you modify the underlying set of fragments.

Comment: @EugenPechanec unfortunately, this did not fix the problem. The fragments still only get created once

Comment: Check Below link its working for me :
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34436011/3392323)

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem and answer in this page solved my problem. Just use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

[Android TabLayout does not display contents anymore as soon as fragment is switched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162007/android-tablayout-does-not-display-contents-anymore-as-soon-as-fragment-is-switc)

Comment: damn. thanks. right answer., it helped me. thanks alot

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use for **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** instead of **FragmentPagerAdapter**

It will work.

Thank you

Comment: Please upvote if worked.. So that others can get help